# How to calculate previous previous 7 days of target acquisitions with formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for a formula that would allow me to look at the previous 7 days customer acquisitions compared to previous targets. Every Monday I need to calculate the previous week's acquisition targets and the percentage to the goal.[image] As you can see in the highlighted cells, those would be the past week's actual acquisitions and the blue column to the left would be the previous week's projections. The blank cells below auto-populate, so the formula would need to account for the most recent 7 days. I have been trying to come up with something, but I don't know how to auto calculate the 7 most recent entries.

Comment: I have tried `=SUMIF(B:B,H:H,today():Today()-7)`, however I get an NA ref saying the argument needs to be a range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close with your attempt in the comment.  Try this:

```
=SUMIFS(H3:H,B3:B,">="&TODAY()-7,B3:B,"<"&TODAY())
```

Comment: That worked—amazing. I realized I should have made the columns visible to make it easier to distinguish. Thank you so much!